# SIGTRAP(TRAP_BRKPT) Crash in CollectionView cellForItemAt IndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am getting this weird crash in my production app. The crash is non frequent and I can't reproduce it.

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  AppName                    0x104a4c040 ViewController.(collectionView(UICollectionView, cellForItemAt : IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell).(closure #1) (ViewController.swift:1018)
1  AppName                    0x104a95270 _T0Ieg_IeyB_TR (Gif.swift)
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1821cd088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1821cd048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1821da378 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1028
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1821d9f10 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182473130 _pthread_wqthread + 1268
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182472c30 start_wqthread + 4
```

I was updating core data object in cellForItemAt IndexPath of collectionView using a background queue. I am using parent-child managed object context to update core data.

In line 1018 I have

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    DatabaseOperations.sharedInstance.incomingMessageRead(true, message.messageId!)
            }
```

Which is located in the cellForItem method. Can anyone let me know what's causing the crash and what can I do to prevent it? Thanks.

Comment: usually sigtrap is for unexpected nil so you could `guard let` this part `message.messageId!` and see if this helps

Comment: I thought so, because the `message.messageId!` is in background async thread, so there is a high chance of deallocating the `message` object. But shouldn't there be an error message like _unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping..._ ?

Comment: Don't run asynchronous tasks in `cellForItemAt`. Cells can be deallocated immediately on scrolling. `cellForItem` is for assigning the **model** to the **view**, not for **controller** stuff

Comment: I am setting the incoming message as `read` when a cell is loaded. I tried running it on the main thread, it causes problem with FRC. Because the collectionView solely depends on FRC. 
What is the best way of doing setting the incoming message as `read`? Thanks

Comment: @sloik please post your comment as answer so that I can mark it accepted if the crash is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @TamimIbnAman ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually sigtrap is for unexpected nil so you could guard let this part:

`message.messageId!`